# Regex: how to know that string contains at least 2 upper case letters?

Tags: java, regex

How to know that string contains at least 2 upper case letters? For example these are valid strings "Lazy Cat", "NOt very lazy cat". Working with Java 1.7.

Comment: Was trying `string.matches("^.*(?=[A-Z]{2,}).*$")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
"^(.*?[A-Z]){2,}.*$"
```

or

```
"^(.*?[A-Z]){2,}"
```

Comment: Why the anchors and the `.*` at the end?

Comment: Because of `$`, It has to be if there are lowercase letters on the end.

Comment: @TedHopp You're right - second solution skips matching end of the string.

Answer (score 9):

This regex works.

```
string.matches(".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*")
```

Comment: Can it be simplified to ".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*" ?

Comment: The ^ and $ are not necessary. They are implied, because `matches()` must match the *whole* String.

Comment: changed it for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I'll now show you a full solution, I'll guide you.

If you don't want to use regex, you can simply loop on the String, chat by char and check whether it's an upper case:

```
for (int i=0;i<myStr.length();i++)
{
     //as @sanbhat suggested, use Character#isUpperCase on each character..
}
```

Comment: That is OK, but I think Regex is simpler.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis Depends.. for me this is easier ;)

Comment: Shouldn't we use `Character.isUpperCase(ch)` ?

Comment: @sanbhat Yes.. That's actually a better idea than mine :)

Comment: just posted like so ;) coincidence.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes.. your answer is better than mine :D

Comment: This is awful. I would downvote it, but it's so bad I doubt it would make any difference or encourage you to write something better

Comment: @Bohemian That is OK,just shared the views.Not cluttering the site with duplicated answers,Just giving some new hints.

Comment: @Bohemian I always love to hear what I did wrong/bad.. Please let me know so I can change it and learn from my mistakes. -1 is good when it's explained. We're all here to learn new things :)

Comment: OK. I believe less code is good (as long as the code is still readable). This problem is clearly a job for regex. Using regex will allow the job to be done in-line: `if (str.matches(".*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*"))`. Writing a loop is doing it "the hard way", which is "bad".

Comment: @Bohemian Yes. Regex might be easier for this, but I was suggesting an alternative "good to know" solution. For others, regex might be more complicated than a simple for-loop. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have somany regex answers right now,

Go for it if you don't want to use `**regex**`,

```
String someString = "abcDS";
int upperCount = 0;
for (char c : someString.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        upperFound++;
    }
}
// upperFound  here weather >2 or not
```

Comment: You should break your loop once your `upperFound` is 2 to stop unnecessary looping

Comment: @Jayamohan  No No,it's a generic method to get total count.If 2 is the requirment,yes that should break there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string.matches("[A-Z]+.*[A-Z]+");
```

Comment: Won't work. In java matches has to match the *whole* string to be true

Comment: Simplest counterexample: "AA"

Comment: That's closer, but it still won't work. For example "aAAa" won't match even your new regex. The plus will consume both AA leaving no capitals left. You need to remove the plus signs.